# Having trouble with apt update kali 4.17

Tags: networking, apt, kali-linux, proxy

This is the error I get when I input `apt update`

```
Err:1 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease
 Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (144.76.200.19). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Hit:2 http://kali.mirror.globo.tech/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
643 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (144.76.200.19). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Connection is fine, I can browse website, ping addresses, clone files. I get the same result with `apt-get update` been stuck on this for a while. I'm not sure if it has something to do with my proxy, `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf` returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should remove the `http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb` repository. For some reason your computer is unable to connect to it, but in any case, you shouldn’t mix repositories on Kali; as [the documentation says](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories),

> **Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely *BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL*.**